# How can I specify multiple variables for the hue parameters when plotting with seaborn?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, pandas-groupby, seaborn

When using *seaborn*, is there a way I can include multiple variables (columns) for the *hue* parameter? Another way to ask this question would be how can I group my data by multiple variables before plotting them on a single x,y axis plot?

I want to do something like below. However currently I am not able to specify two variables for the *hue* parameter.:

```
sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', hue=['Legendary', 'Stage'], data=df)
```

For example, assume I have a pandas DataFrame like below containing an a [Pokemon database](https://elitedatascience.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Pokemon.csv) obtained via [this](https://elitedatascience.com/python-seaborn-tutorial) tutorial.

[image]

I want to plot on the x-axis the *pokedex #*, and the y-axis the *Attack*. However, I want to data to be grouped by both *Stage* and *Legendary*. Using *matplotlib*, I wrote a custom function that groups the dataframe by *['Legendary','Stage']*, and then iterates through each group for the plotting (see results below). Although my custom function works as intended, I was hoping this can be achieved simply by seaborn. I am guessing there must be other people what have attempted to visualize more than 3 variables in a single plot using seaborn?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
grouping_variables = ['Stage','Legendary']
group_1 = df.groupby(grouping_variables)
for group_1_label, group_1_df in group_1:
    ax.scatter(group_1_df['#'], group_1_df['Attack'], label=group_1_label)
ax_legend = ax.legend(title=grouping_variables)
```

[image]

Edit 1:

Note: In the example I provided, I grouped the data by obly two variables (ex: Legendary and Stage). However, other situations may require arbitrary number of variables (ex: 5 variables).

Answer (score 13):

You can leverage the fact that `hue` accepts either a column name, or a sequence of the same length as your data, listing the color categories to assign each data point to. So...

```
sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', hue='Stage', data=df)
```

... is basically the same as:

```
sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', hue=df['Stage'], data=df)
```

You typically wouldn't use the latter, it's just more typing to achieve the same thing -- unless you want to construct a custom sequence on the fly:

```
sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', data=df,
            hue=df[['Legendary', 'Stage']].apply(tuple, axis=1))
```

[image: Seaborn plot using two columns for hue]

The way you build the sequence that you pass via `hue` is entirely up to you, the only requirement is that it must have the same length as your data, and if an array-like, it must be one-dimensional, so you can't just pass `hue=df[['Legendary', 'Stage']]`, you have to somehow concatenate the columns into one. I chose `tuple` as the simplest and most versatile way, but if you want to have more control over the formatting, build a `Series` of strings. I'll save it into a separate variable here for better readability and so that I can assign it a name (which will be used as the legend title), but you don't have to:

```
hue = df[['Legendary', 'Stage']].apply(
    lambda row: f"{row.Legendary}, {row.Stage}", axis=1)
hue.name = 'Legendary, Stage'
sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', hue=hue, data=df)
```

[image: Seaborn plot using two columns for hue, fancier version]

Answer (score 6):

In seaborn's `scatterplot()`, you can combine both a `hue=` and a `style=` parameter to produce different markers and different colors for each combinations

example (taken verbatim from [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html#seaborn.scatterplot)):

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip",
                     hue="day", style="time", data=tips)
```

[image]

Comment: nice add up but not the topic of the question.

Answer (score 4):

To use *hue* of `seaborn.relplot`, consider concatenating the needed groups into a single column and then run the plot on new variable:

```
def run_plot(df, flds):
   # CREATE NEW COLUMN OF CONCATENATED VALUES
   df['_'.join(flds)] =  pd.Series(df.reindex(flds, axis='columns')
                                     .astype('str')
                                     .values.tolist()
                                  ).str.join('_')

   # PLOT WITH hue
   sns.relplot(x='#', y='Attack', hue='_'.join(flds), data=random_df, aspect=1.5)
   plt.show()

   plt.clf()
   plt.close()
```

To demonstrate with random data

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

### DATA
np.random.seed(22320)
random_df = pd.DataFrame({'#': np.arange(1,501),
                          'Name': np.random.choice(['Bulbasaur', 'Ivysaur', 'Venusaur', 
                                                    'Charmander', 'Charmeleon'], 500),
                          'HP': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Attack': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Defense': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Sp. Atk': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Sp. Def': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Speed': np.random.randint(1, 100, 500),
                          'Stage': np.random.randint(1, 3, 500),
                          'Legend': np.random.choice([True, False], 500)
                          })
```

**Plots**

```
run_plot(random_df, ['Legend', 'Stage'])
```

[image: Two Group Plot Output]

```
run_plot(random_df, ['Legend', 'Stage', 'Name'])
```

[image: Three Group Plot]